# Change Button Position on UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uibutton

how can I change the Position for a UIButton on a `UIScrollView` in `ViewDiDLoad` I tryed this but it does not work:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {

    //I5

    Brandwein.frame= CGRectMake(45, 98, 100, 100);
    Tee.frame= CGRectMake(178, 377, 100, 100);
} else {

    //IP4
    Brandwein.frame= CGRectMake(45, 75, 100, 100);      
    Tee.frame= CGRectMake(178, 338, 100, 100);

}
```

Tee and Brandwein are the Button's 
Using Autolayout

Hope for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` - this is the correct place for controller-managed layout-related code.

Comment: No Effect. Buuton's on the position they have in the IB at not the position I will give them

Comment: is this because i using autolayout?

Comment: More than likely, yes. You shouldn't need custom code if you're using auto-layout, you just need to set up the constraints properly so that it does what you want at *any* size.

Comment: I can explain what is my suggestion: I have 6 Button's. And 2 Column's, also 3 Button per column and this 6 Button should display in the middle of the view in 4Inch and 3.5 inch.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Turn off auto-layout. Put the buttons inside a view. Set the auto-resize for the view so that it centers vertically (no resize, relative top/bottom). This way the buttons will stay fixed relative to each other and the group will center vertically.

Comment: Thanks for your hint I have do this app now with auto-layout turned off and everything looks good :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding it to the `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` method instead of `ViewDidLoad`.